# vitest Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vitest

I am trying to unit test my router object in Express but inside the unit test file the object returns undefined

Here is a minimal version of my app

**src/config/apiVersion.js**

```
// update major versions here
const version = '/v2'

export default version
```

**src/routes/index.js**

```js
import express from 'express'
import {
  healthRouter,
  healthUrl
} from './health/index.js'

const router = express.Router()

// add new routes here
const allRoutes = [
  {
    path: healthUrl,
    route: healthRouter
  }
]

// tell the router to use the routes you added
allRoutes.forEach((route) => {
  router.use(route.path, route.route)
})

export default router
```

**src/routes/health/index.js**

```js
import express from 'express'
import { healthController } from '../../controllers/health/index.js'

const healthRouter = express.Router()

const healthUrl = '/health'

healthRouter.route('/')
  .get(healthController)

export {
  healthRouter,
  healthUrl
}
```

**src/app.js (note I omitted most of the `app.use`'s such as app.us(cors()) for example**

```
// version is just the string '/v2'
import version from './config/apiVersion.js'
import router from './routes/index.js'

const app = express()

// some other app.use's here omitted like app.use(cors)

// add routes
app.use(`${version}`, router)

// custom 404 to handle non-existent paths/typos on paths
app.use((req, res) => {
  res.status(404).send({ error: 'Path does not exist, check for typos. If querying /soap you also need vendor and method in the path' })
})

// custom error handler
app.use((err, req, res) => {
  appLogger.error('There was an error: ' + err.stack)
  res.status(500).send('Something broke!')
})

export default app
```

Here is my test file

```js
import router from '../../../src/routes/index.js'

// to make sure the number of routes doesn't change without a new test added
const actualNumberRoutes = 2

describe('router', () => {
  it('should return all the routes', () => {
    let numberOfRoutes = 0
    router.stack.forEach((layer) => {
      expect(layer.name).toEqual('router')
      numberOfRoutes += 1
    })
    expect(numberOfRoutes).toEqual(actualNumberRoutes)
  })
})
```

And the error for this file where router is coming up as undefined

[image]

Comment: Why didn't you include the part highlighted in error?

Comment: How do you declare `version` in `./config/apiVersion.js`?

Comment: Let me add that one too actually

Answer (score 0):

Try to provide your app to use routes after importing your respective route files like this.

```
   import healthRouter from 'src/routes/health/index.js';
   import router from '../../../src/routes/index.js';
   const app=express();

   app.use("your_path",router);
   app.use("your_health_path",healthRouter);
```